# How to read keyboard/barcode reader data and send it to another pc?

Tags: usb, keyboard

Im working on a project which is summary reading barcode reader data and send it to another pc. Simply i wanted to sniff the barcode reader data.

In the project i will connect the barcode reader to my raspberry pi, write some codes on it for listening usb port, and then when any barcode readed from barcode reader raspberry pi should get the readed barcode and send it to another pc which is also connected with usb ports of raspberry pi.

They both should be ( barcode reader & pc) connected with usb ports.

According to my researches, for example raspberry pi 3 has 4 usb ports. But i didnt find how to read and send data at the same time with different ports. There is some host and slave issue which i didnt get clearly.

For this issue;

Which type of raspberry should i use if it is possible?

Is it possible to do it with not adding add another card like usb host card on raspberry pi?

What is the host/slave problem here?

Answer (score 1):

A USBNET cable has a Chipset to enable negotiation of USB Host / Slave Mode, and might address your Pi to PC needs. You can find some additional thoughts on it here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=131042

As for which Pi, what you're trying to accomplish sounds pretty simple, as far as not demanding a lot of processor power, so really any of the Pis should work. Given they are all the same price, go for the Pi3.

Comment: thanks for your response. I will try and let you know. Is there any other alternative ways?

Answer (score 0):

Usb barcode readers behaves as keyboard in most cases. You can run a program that waits for keyboard input, and send the data to another host.